# Check if laptop is asleep

Tags: ssh, framebuffer, sleep

Does anyone know to check via SSH or bash script whether or not my laptop has "fallen asleep". For some reason whenever my laptop falls asleep my drawings (on /dev/fb0) are over ridden by the framebuffer terminal (yes I've tried turning this off but then my drawings are just overridden by a black screen) when I hit the space bar or something and my computer wakes up.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need a script to know whether your computer is asleep?

Comment: Like I described above, when my computer falls asleep and I wake it up for some reason all the fb0 art that I drew gets overriden by the framebuffer terminal. And incase you suggest I disable the framebuffer terminal, I have already tried that and my fb0 art still went away, I want to know when my laptop falls asleep so I can re-draw the image when it wakes up.

Comment: You should change the address of the fbo art to a different address.

Comment: Hmm, could you explain how that would help?

Comment: /dev/fbo is in /dev which is for disc files. Either it is taken by the system, or the system "cleans up" /dev when it falls asleep.

Comment: Well if I don't write to /dev/fb0 then my framebuffer art won't show up on the screen at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39204/discussion-between-ktb92677-and-john).